# Pushing from Android Studio to git pushes all projects projects to github repository

Tags: git, android-studio, github

Every time I use the VCS in android studio or use the terminal to push an project into GitHub repository, all the other projects are also pushed in the same repository.

I've checked my directory when I push and also checked with `git ls-tree HEAD` to see the files being pushed.
The other projects aren't listed there but when I open my repository, there are all my other projects from AndroidStudioProjects in the same repository.

Why?

Comment: looks like you have all your projects in 1 repository

Comment: Ya, when I push, all my projects are pushed to 1 repository. I want one repo for each project.

Comment: then you have to **create** one repo for each project

Comment: I created a repository, used the link to push my project from the terminal (and another way from VCS as well) but both ways, the repository had my other projects as well.

Comment: then you likely pushed the directory where all your projects are, not the individual project directories.

Comment: any way your question does not relate to android. It's only git-related

Comment: Using the default VCS settings to create a new repository and push the project resulted in the same thing. So, I assumed the question would be related to Android Studio as well.

Comment: are you 100% sure that your *projects* are not the one lagre project which you used to create a new VCS repository?>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check in command-line, and look for any `.git` subfolder.

If you find only one:

```
main-folder
  .git
  project1
  project2
```

Then any push from any project would push everything.

You want to find multiple .git folders:

```
main-folder
  project1
    .git
  project2
    .git
```

Comment: Thanks. I checked it and it showed all the projects. So, I deleted the .git and did a git-init in individual projects and it worked.